# sklearn imputer drop column with missing values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I am learning currently about [sklearn imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) and I found that there is one strategy that isn't implemented by the imputers.

I would like to build a pipeline that deletes the columns with any missing values or delete all the rows with missing values.

Why do I want this?

Because I would like to do a grid search and find the defect of any imputing method on my RMSE or classification score.

Is there a way I can do this with sklearn pipeline? Or should I create my own imputer?

If this has been asked before, feel free to suggest closing the question and pointing me out to the correct resource.

For more context, I have 21 features and 1000 data points, only one column has missing values and those missing values are 50% of the values in the columns. I just want to explore the effect of the missing value imputation method on my classifier's accuracy and f1 score.

Comment: So you want to compare missingRowsRemoved vs missingColumnsRemoved vs imputationMethod1 vs imputationMethod2 etc? Is this right?

Comment: Yeah.. that is right @RSale

Comment: This needs more context. What kind of data do you use. What kind of problem are you solving? You are doing a grid search on what?

Comment: Imputing is an art and choosing the right methods depends entirely on the data you have.

Comment: It is numerical data basically, only one column has missing data  I am not doing grid search yet but I am just exploring the effect of missing values on the accuracy score.

Comment: Such a transformer wouldn't really be an "imputer".  I don't know of a common package that provides such either.  The "drop any column containing any missings" would be fairly easy to build out as a custom transformer.  The "drop any row containing any missings" would be much more difficult, since sklearn assumes throughout that the rows stay in a fixed order and are neither dropped nor added.  You might be able to make use of the `imblearn` package and its resampling pipelines, but it would be a little hacky.

Comment: Ahhh.. look like i miss the whole point of imputer.. yeah you are right .. it wouldn't be an imputer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using autoimpute library. It's probably the best tool currently to deal with datasets that have missing values.

It has a function that does exactly what you asked, deletes rows with any missing values.

```
from autoimpute.imputations import MiceImputer, SingleImputer, listwise_delete

listwise_delete(df, inplace=True, verbose=False)
```

In general, sklearn's imputer is very limited in its usefulness and autoimpute is able to fill a lot of gaps. More specifically, it allows to:

- Explicitly set columns that you would like to treat as variables in calculating the imputed values
- Set different imputation algorithms for every column or a set of columns

```
si_dict_col = SingleImputer(
    strategy={"gender":"categorical", "salary": "pmm", "weight": "pmm"},
    predictors={"gender": ["salary", "weight", "looks"], "salary": ["weight", "gender"])
```

- There are built-in methods to visualize different imputation method's results

```
plot_imp_scatter(data_het_miss, "x", "y", "least squares")
```

It also follows sklearn's patterns and can be substituted for sklearn's own imputer function in the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this.. i will check it out

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi glad to be able to help! Does my post answer your question?

Comment: I haven't tried it , once I tried it I will mark it as the answer.